How do I create a Next.js (app based router) API GET with Prisma that includes a query param and call it in a component?
I am creating a searchable select drop-down that needs to call the API with the search term on enter. I am having trouble finding examples of passing a searchParam into the GET.
For this example I am going to use a db table of 'groceries'.
I have created a groceries/route.ts with a GET. I have no problem with the GET and returning all groceries and calling that. I need to pass in a search parameter in the fieldName: {contains: searchParm}.
Examples here or links to good examples of both the API and the calling of the API in the component would be super helpful.
